# Table1 r function

Tags: r

I'm using the r function `table1()` to get descriptive statistics by group

`table1(~ factor(sex) + age + factor(ulcer) + thickness | status, data=melanoma2)`

see example [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/table1/vignettes/table1-examples.html#using-abbreviated-code-to-specify-a-custom-renderer)

for categorical variables, I want the percentage with two digits after the decimal : x.xx%
and add for continuous variables the N,Q1,Q3
Is that possible ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer for question 2: "How to add for continuous variables the N,Q1,Q3 Is that possible?"

You could add `render.continuous..` to your code:

```
table1(~ factor(sex) + age + factor(ulcer) + thickness | status, 
       data=melanoma2, render.continuous=c(.="N", .="Q1", .="Q3",.="Mean", .="SD", .="Median [Min, Max]"))
```

[image]